# php OOP: confused about a method that returns an interface

Tags: php, oop, interface, zend-framework2

This code is ZF2, but this feels like it might be a more general OOP question because its about some confusion I have with interfaces. This example is a little long winded, but I wanted to use all of my actually code to show everything that I'm doing.

So here is the code snippet that is the source of my confusion:

```
// References
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;

// Class definition
public function getAuthService()
{
if (! $this->authservice) {
   $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
   $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'user','email','password', 'MD5(?)');
   $authService = new AuthenticationService();
   $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
   $this->authservice = $authService;
}
return $this->authservice;
}

public function processAction()
//
$this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
   ->setIdentity($this->request->getPost('email'))
   ->setCredential($this->request->getPost('password'));

$result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
if ($result->isValid()) {
   $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($this->request->getPost('email'));
   return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
      'controller' => 'login', 
      'action' => 'confirm' 
   ));
}
```

In the first method we construct a new [Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Authentication.Adapter.DbTable.html) with some params, pass it to an instance of [Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Authentication.AuthenticationService.html) and then return that instance of AuthenticationService.

In the next method we call that method ($this->getAuthService()) to get an instance of AuthenticationService, call the AuthenticationService's getAdapter() method and then start calling Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable method on the object returned.

Here is what confuses me. Look at the definition [getAdater()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Authentication.AuthenticationService.html#getAdapter). It doesn't actually return an instance of Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable it only returns an interface: Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface and this interface doesn't define any Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable methods.

So if getAdapter() is only returning an interface how is it I am able to call Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable methods on the object returned?

Sorry if this question is confusing to read I'm confused about what's happening here on a pretty fundamental level so its difficult for me to be more lucid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions says that it can return any AdapterInterface (meaning any class that implements it) and not the AdapterInterface directly. As it is extended by DbTableAuthAdapter, you are able to use DbTable methods.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. The object it returns must implement the interface. But I'm still confused- what is the advantage of requiring the object _returned_ to implement the interface? You shouldn't have to go any further than requiring the object passed to setAdapter() to implement the interface because at that point you will know any adapter retrieved by getAdapter() would have to implement it. It seems redundant.

Comment: This is so called "Strategy" pattern (could probably be also found under different names too). It basically allows Authentication Service to work with different implementations of AdapterInterfaces, without knowing anything on their implementations besides few special case functions that are defined in interface. More info: http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html (at the end)

Comment: The info comes from the DocBlock: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Authentication/AuthenticationService.php#L49. It's not a requirement, it's merely documentation - it's helps things like IDEs know that if some code calls `->getAdapter()`, what sort of object is returned

Comment: hmm now things are a bit clearer. Would this also explain why using ctags to jump around the Zend library wasn't behaving like I was expecting it to?

Comment: My 2 cents - Firstly an interface can **never** be instantiated; Their job is to enforce a public API to any class implementing them; in the case of the auth adapter it is the `authenticate()` method that is enforced - meaning that any class that wants to authenticate needs that method and the auth service has no idea how that is implemented. The design is also known as the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

`Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` is an example of how to respect [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles with a [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) approach and (arguably) a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) implementation (wow, that's a mouthful...).

The architecture of the class is a bit confusing, but I'll try to eviscerate it as an exercise for my understanding of design patterns. (Please, by all means correct me wherever I'm wrong).

The first point of [Dipendency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) in this case is that `AuthenticationService` should not depend on the implementation details of any low level authentication procedure, it rather should depend on an abstraction, from whom it only needs an `authenticate()` method encapsulating the *strategy behaviour*.
(oddly enough, the service also provide the same method by itself and it's where the adapter is actually consumed, being a wrapper around the adapter's method, but let's ignore that :-p).

So the service doesn't need to care about *how* the authentication is done, it just needs an outcome.
Enters the `AdapterInterface` contract, put in place as a *strategy interface* to define the requirements of the behaviour, that being just returning a `Result` instance from `authenticate()`.

`AuthenticationService` can thus be considered the *strategy context*.

All this is done primarily to allow plugging in and out different `AdapterInterface` implementations, without having to change `AuthenticationService` itself, hence the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) is also respected.

Since the `AdapterInterface` is an abstract dependency and it is made accessible with a getter, the getter must return an abstraction as well, it would make no sense to return anything different!

Yes, the dependency could probably be completely obfuscated, but having accessors helps with the unit testing (you may have to access mocked dependencies to simulate different behaviours), plus the current implementation of the service, as you can see within your own example, requires the service consumer (the Controller, in your case) to manually set some context on the adapter before calling the authentication procedure (and this actually breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), but that's another story).

Now, as far as I understand the word 'adapter' has been a bit misused, because to my eyes this has nothing to do with the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), which is for interoperation between incompatible interfaces. The various 'adapters' should not cause any concern about any incompatibility whatsoever, they are actually compatible with each other by providing a common behaviour enforced by their contract but encapsulated within themselves.

To lay aside any criticism, it may be worth noticing that the whole `Zend\Authentication` component is basically a port of the old ZF1 `Zend_Auth`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a loosely typed language, which means that you can call any methods on any object, no matter what type hints there are. If the  method ultimately does not exist you'll get a runtime error. On the other hand, even in type safe languages functions can return any object that is a subtype of the documented type. This is a special case of the Liskov substitution principle.